# Best way to remove SQLite labels from database query

Tags: android, sqlite

I hope this isn't a repeat question.

I have a database in my app that stores and returns calibration offsets for an audio output. I have an alertDialog that allows the user to choose which profile to apply. The issue is that I want raw int values after the user has chosen, but the database return is in the following format:

```
calibrationDB [calibrationConfidence=1, systemName=Nexus7,DT770,250ohm, fileUsed=1, f125L=1, f250L=2, f500L=3, f1000L=4, f1500L=5, f2000L=6, f3000L=7, f4000L=8, f6000L=9, f8000L=10, f125R=1, f250R=2, f500R=3, f1000R=4, f1500R=5, f2000R=6, f3000R=7, f4000R=8, f6000R=9, f8000R=10]
```

Essentially I was wondering if there was a fast or efficient way to turn off the labels (e.g. f125L=) from my result. If not, what's the easiest way to remove them from the string? The result I would like is:

```
Nexus7,DT770,250ohm, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
```

As I am then going to set these to a map.

EDIT: The code used to get this result is a get all calibrations query:

```
public List<calibrationDB> getAllCalibrations() {
    List<calibrationDB> calibrationDBs = new ArrayList<calibrationDB>();

    // Build query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CALIBRATION;

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    // Get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // Loop through all the rows and populate the list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            calibrationDB cdb = new calibrationDB();

            cdb.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
      cdb.setCalibrationConfidence(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CALIBRATION_CONFIDENCE)));
            cdb.setSystemName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SYSTEM_NAME)));
            cdb.setFileUsed(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FILE_USED)));
            cdb.setf125L(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_125L)));
            cdb.setf250L(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_250L)));
            cdb.setf500L(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_500L)));
            cdb.setf1000L(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_1000L)));
            cdb.setf1500L(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_1500L)));
            cdb.setf2000L(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_2000L)));
            cdb.setf3000L(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_3000L)));
            cdb.setf4000L(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_4000L)));
            cdb.setf6000L(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_6000L)));
            cdb.setf8000L(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_8000L)));
            cdb.setf125R(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_125R)));
            cdb.setf250R(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_250R)));
            cdb.setf500R(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_500R)));
            cdb.setf1000R(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_1000R)));
            cdb.setf1500R(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_1500R)));
            cdb.setf2000R(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_2000R)));
            cdb.setf3000R(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_3000R)));
            cdb.setf4000R(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_4000R)));
            cdb.setf6000R(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_6000R)));
            cdb.setf8000R(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_8000R)));

            // Add calibration to calibrations list
            calibrationDBs.add(cdb);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    Log.d("getAllCalibrations()", calibrationDBs.toString());

    // Return list
    return calibrationDBs;
}
```

After further inverstigation; am I correct in thinking that if I write a query to get each of the columns individually, it will come without the labels?

EDIT 2:

When I get the result from the database, I am using the following to adapt it to a list view in an alertDialog:

```
  // Get all the calibrations in the database
    List<calibrationDB> allCalibrations = db.getAllCalibrations();
    // Set up a Sting Array
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Iterate the list and set to strings
    for (int i = 0;i<= allCalibrations.size()-1;i++){

        stringList.add(String.valueOf(allCalibrations.get(i)));
    }


    // Set to a char sequence for the list view
    CharSequence[] calibSeq = stringList.toArray(new CharSequence[stringList.size()]);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where's your code? The problem with it is that it's doing exactly what you're telling it to do.

Comment: Hi @laalto, apologies, please see my edit.

Comment: So it's the `calibrationDBs.toString()` that is doing exactly what you're telling it to do?

Comment: The labels are added by `calibrationDB.toString()`.

Comment: @ laalto Apologies if I'm not following, but to clarify: I don't want the labels in the return string from the database. What method would I need to use in order to have it not return all of the "f125L=" labels? I appreciate that the code is likely doing as I've told it to, but I'm fairly new to the concepts and would like to know what to use so that it doesn't do that.

Comment: @CL. Is there a way to get it to a string without the labels then? thanks for the help so far guys.

Comment: The database does not return a string, or labels. Show your implementation of `calibrationDB.toString()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I'm realising my mistakes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the method implementation that is causing the effect I'm getting, entirely my own fault. A mixture of not knowing what I'm doing, and following too many tutorials in which I don;t know what the methods are doing properly. I think I have it down now though! This was the one:

```
    public String toString() {
    return "calibrationDB [calibrationConfidence=" + calibrationConfidence + ", systemBIG DIX!Name=" + systemName + ", fileUsed=" + fileUsed +
            ", f125L=" + f125L + ", f250L=" + f250L + ", f500L=" + f500L + ", f1000L=" + f1000L + ", f1500L=" + f1500L + ", f2000L=" + f2000L + ", f3000L=" + f3000L + ", f4000L=" + f4000L + ", f6000L=" + f6000L + ", f8000L=" + f8000L +
            ", f125R=" + f125R + ", f250R=" + f250R + ", f500R=" + f500R + ", f1000R=" + f1000R + ", f1500R=" + f1500R + ", f2000R=" + f2000R + ", f3000R=" + f3000R + ", f4000R=" + f4000R + ", f6000R=" + f6000R + ", f8000R=" + f8000R  + "]";
}
```

Which is the toString() implementation that was causing my issue. I've modified it now and have the result I wanted direct from the database.

Thanks for the help @laalto & @CL.